# Android Studio cant resolve error setOnClickListener

Tags: java, android-studio

Hi I can't seem to build this.. It states that it cannot resolve the `OnClickListener`. The onClick action is performed the back button that goes to the main activity.

```
Button bnCompute = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.bnCompute);
    bnCompute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener());

    {
        @Override

        public void onClick (View view){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Compute All!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        EditText etBeauty = (EditText) MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.etBeauty);
        EditText etBody = (EditText) MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.etBody);
        EditText etIntelligence = (EditText) MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.etIntelligence);

        int total = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(etBeauty.getText())) + Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(etBody.getText()))
                + Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(etIntelligence.getText()));

        Intent actSummary = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Score.class);
        actSummary.putExtra("total", Integer.toString(total));
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(actSummary);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have implemented `onClick`outside the scope of listener. 
It should be something like this below :

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    //Your mistake is on this line.
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    });
```